# How to capture Ctrl key is pressed in eclipse RAP

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I want to know when the Ctrl key is released in eclipse RAP, I achieved it in
RCP. But learnt it behaves differently on RAP. Any suggestions on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC RAP does not send key events if only a modifier key (such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, etc.) is pressed or released. Only for *regular* keys, events are sent and the `event.stateMask` can be queried which modifier keys are currently pressed.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> will send `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` where `character` is A and `stateMask` is Ctrl.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> only will not send an event.

If in doubt, a simple `Shell` with a `KeyListener` attached that prints the events to `System.out` will help you clarify things.

Comment: But the problem is the key listeners are not called at the right time. Which listener should I use for this?

Comment: There is no way in RAP to get notified when only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key was pressed.

Comment: I mean, I can get which key was pressed from stateMask as you mentioned, but will the key listeners grt notfied when a key is pressed?

Comment: As I said, the key listener will only be notified if a _regular_ key was pressed, with or without a modifier key. If only a modified key like Ctrl was pressed, not event will be sent.

Comment: My purpose is to select multiple items with a Ctrl click. So, here I never use individual keys with Ctrl.

Comment: Which widget (List?, Table?, ...?) do you use to select multiple items?

Comment: I'm using a ListViewer to Ctrl select, after releasing the Ctrl key, my method should be called.

Comment: If the `List` widget was created with `SWT.MULTI`it should allow to Ctrl+select items. The selection event will notify if items are selected or unselected. Why are you trying to get the modifier state?

Comment: I want to do immediately after the elements are selected (i.e., after Ctrl key is released). That is the reason I want to do this.

Comment: Use a `SelectionListener`. Its `widgetSelected` event is sent whenever the selection changes.